# IE SCRIPT5: Access is denied. being thrown by same-domain ajax request with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

When using jQuery `$.post` to submit a form, I'm getting the `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.` error in IE. Everything I have seen regarding this error says it is caused by cross-domain requests, but my request is not cross-domain. What else could be causing this? It works perfectly in all other browsers.

Comment: Are you 1000% sure your request is not cross-domain? Switching protocols (`http://` to `https://`) is regarded cross-domain. Using different subdomains (`www.domain.com` vs `domain.com`) is regarded cross-domain. Using different ports is regarded cross-domain.

Comment: @Pekka They're both https to the same domain (no subdomains). I even get the error with a relative URL.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem, using jQuery 1.8.0.

After upgrading to version 1.8.3 the problem was solved.